# How to pass simple value form ui form to spring webflow

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

When I am doing form submission, I would like to send simple boolean value.
I don't wanna create special model for that in view state.

So my question is, can I pass value without model as it is simple single value using spring webflow. Or do I have to create model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use this in your view `myView`:

```
<form:form action="${flowExecutionUrl}">
    <input type="checkbox" id="booleanValue" name="booleanValue"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="_eventId_submitValue" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>
```

and in your flow:

```
<view-state id="myView">
    <transition on="submitValue">
        <set name="myBooleanValue" value="requestParameters['booleanValue']"/>
        <!-- do something with your value -->
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

please note that `<input type="checkbox"/>` will only send a value if it's checked ("on")

Comment: Thanks it works. It'is strange that it is not in Spring webflow documentation.